# ParseExact: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for specific culture

Tags: mono, culture

This very simple expression is calculated correctly on .NET 4.71 and .NetCore 2.0

```
DateTime.ParseExact( 
    "9-Фев-18 15:45", "d-MMM-yy HH:mm", 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "ru-RU" ) )
```

but on Mono 5.8 (both Windows & Linux) cause error:

```
System.FormatException : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Any idea for fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reproduce this error.

I can only think of three options:

1. do not use that dates (only use [dates in ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
2. if you can't avoid these dates (I guess not), then parse them yourself. I anyway would file a bug in Xamarin Bugzilla.
3. Use [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxredhat) instead of Mono. I can install it in Manjaro with `pacman -S dotnet-sdk dotnet-runtime`. Unfortunately, I've checked this out and it does not work either (maybe they are using Mono's implementation?).

I guess you can only parse them yourself.

Hope this (somehow) helps.

Comment: I cannot change date format (external source).

Current I use replacement to English months, but it is not good solution.

I am going to use NetCore, but there are several other issues that do not allow to refuse Mono right now